# Minimum length to travel all nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm

We are given a graph containing N nodes with M edges between them and each edge is having some weight associated with it.Now we need to travel through all the vertices in such a way that total length traveled is minimum. 
We assume that we need to start from Node 1 always.

Like say we have 2 nodes and 2 edges.

Edge 1 : It is between 1 and 2 and length is 4

Edge 2 : It is between 1 and 3 and length is 2

Then here minimum length need to be traveled is 8 as one will start from node 1. Then to node 3 then back to node 1 and then to node 2.

How to do this problem ? Please help.

As being discussed in comments and answer provided that its TSP I coded it,but can anyone help me find why this code gives INT_MIN as answer

```
#define MAXN 20
bool visited[MAXN][(1<<MAXN)+5];
int value[MAXN][(1<<MAXN)+5]; 
int weight[MAXN][MAXN] = {{0, 2, 4},{2, 0, -1},{4, -1, 0}};
int DP(int currentPos,int currentMask,int N){
if(currentMask==(1<<N)-1){
    visited[currentPos][currentMask]=true;
    return value[currentPos][currentMask];
}
if(visited[currentPos][currentMask]){
    return value[currentPos][currentMask];
}
int ans=INT_MAX;
int cost;
visited[currentPos][currentMask]=true;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    if(weight[currentPos][i]!=-1 && ((currentMask)&(1<<i))==0){
        cost=DP(i,(currentMask)|(1 << i),N)+weight[currentPos][i];
        ans=min(ans,cost);
    }
}
return value[currentPos][currentMask]=ans;

}
int main ()
{
    memset (visited, false, sizeof (visited));
    printf ("Cost : %d\n", DP (0, 1,3));
}
```

Comment: This is the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is NP-Complete, so there is no known efficient solution to it, but there are some known heuristics and approximations if you can sattle for "good enough", and not optimal

Comment: @amit I had edited the post and added a code too. but it does not provide correct answer. What can be reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a lock at [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or A* (advanced Dijkstra). There is some pseudocode on the wiki page and you will find a lot of implementations around in any language you wish... I think it is one of the most important pathfindign algorithms.

Comment: But Dijsktra dont do this. Its single source shortest path algorithm and don't ensure that overall sum of length is minimum

Comment: Do check the requirement of the question

Comment: If I get you right then Dijkstra can of course handle it. Or why do you think it is called Dijkstra's shortest path? Please be more specific and best add a picture of the example graph if you can. This will explain your problem far better than any word!

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the NP-Hard [travelling salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem. The only difference is that your start node is fixed and you seem to be able to visit nodes more than once.

There are a lot of algorithms that you can use. Unfortunately, none are very efficient for large number of nodes. If you don't need the absolute best solution, there are approximate algorithms that can help.

Comment: How is this travelling salesman problem. Assume that number of nodes are only 20. Please provide a pseudocode for it.

Comment: I had made a small and precise code for TSP but getting wrong answer on above example.Can you please check it once